# ¿Como se envían mensajes con XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html5

Recientemente he averiguado que con XMLHttpRequest se pueden hacer chats como este:
http://chat.plasticshore.com/

Así que me aventuré a hacer el siguiente código:

```
<body bgcolor="black">
<table id="t"bgcolor="#00BBBB"style="border:4px solid #006666"></table>
<script>
if('WebSocket' in window){alert("WebSocket supported")}else{alert("Your shitty browser doesn't support WebSocket, sorry.")}
name=prompt("Enter your name, please.")
net=new XMLHttpRequest
if(name==""){name="¿?"}
onkeydown=function(){net.send(
'row=t.insertRow(0)'+
'c1=row.insertCell(0)'+
'c2=row.insertCell(1)'+
'c1.innerHTML='+name+
'c1.style.backgroundColor="#00FF00"'+
'c2.innerHTML='+prompt("Enter your message.")+
'c2.style.backgroundColor="#0000FF"'
)}
net.onopen=function(){
net.send(
'row=t.insertRow(0)'+
'c1=row.insertCell(0)'+
'c2=row.insertCell(1)'+
'c1.innerHTML='+name+
'c1.style.backgroundColor="#00FF00"'+
'c2.innerHTML="Has connected sucessfully."'+
'c2.style.backgroundColor="#00FFFF"'
)}
net.onerror=function(error){
'row=t.insertRow(0)'+
'c1=row.insertCell(0)'+
'c1.innerHTML='+error+
'c1.colSpan="2"'+
'c1.style.backgroundColor="#FF0000"'
}
net.onmessage=function(e){e.data}
</script>
</body>
```

Así que lo estuve probando, y lo extraño es que no daba ningún error en Mozilla al igual que en chrome, en cambio, cuando pulsaba una tecla y aceptaba la función con el fin de enviar el mensaje, se me bloqueaba y me daba estos errores:
Mozilla:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Chrome:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

Obviamente, para ello necesitas la función net.open(), pero ¿Qué pongo en la función para que me acepte la conexión?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es un método seguro para enviar los XHR:

```js
send_xhr=(method,url)=>{
  net=new XMLHttpRequest()
  net.open(method,url)
  net.send()
  net.onload = (e) => {
    console.log(net.responseText)
    //Para limpiar la RAM es necesario borrar la función.
    delete this
  }
}

text=send_xhr("GET", "//raw.githubusercontent.com/rnrneverdies/ImageLoadingPattern/master/README.md")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Obviamente, para ello necesitas la función net.open(), pero... ¿Qué pongo en la función para que me acepte la conexión?

La funcion open espera 2 parametros requeridos: Metodo y URL

Ej.

```
net.open('GET','/url/del/recurso');
```

Debes tener en cuenta que no puedes pedir cualquier recurso, por ejemplo: no puedes pedir alguna URL de Gmail. Solo puedes pedir (o enviar con POST) recursos que estén en el mismo servidor que la pagina en ejecución o que estén en cualquier servidor que autorice a tu origen (la dirección de tu servidor) a acceder a su recurso. Esta restriccion/limitacion es la columna vertebral de la seguridad de un navegador y se la conoce como **politica del mismo** origen y esta controlado por unas cabeceras especiales de HTTP comúnmente conocidas como CORS.

Un ejemplo completo seria algo así:

```js
var net = new XMLHttpRequest();

net.onload = function(e) {
  console.log(net.responseText); 
}

net.open("GET", "//raw.githubusercontent.com/rnrneverdies/ImageLoadingPattern/master/README.md");
net.send();
```

Este ejemplo, invoca una URL externa al mismo origen (stacksnippet vs GitHub) y debido a que GitHub lo permite es posible obtener el recurso.

Ademas de las restricciones que te mencione hay algunas excepciones como la que usa el ejemplo de arriba, si quieres saber mas sobre [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) y sobre la [política del mismo origen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), sigue los enlaces.

Salu2

## Uso del metodo POST

POST funciona bien para enviar datos al servidor. Eres libre de enviar cualquier contenido, pero como regla general, debes incluir siempre el tipo de contenido que envias, este ejemplo es para enviar JSON, no puedo mostrarte como funciona, pues se necesita un server side que reciba la solicitud y no es posible hacerlo con StackSnippets.

```
var net = new XMLHttpRequest();

net.onload = function(e) {
  console.log(net.responseText); 
}

var datos = { hola: "mundo" };
var datos_json = JSON.stringify(datos);

net.open("POST", "/url/que/recibe/el/post");

net.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

net.send(datos_json);
```

El lado servidor, lo puedes crear con cualquier framework, lo importante es programarlo para recibir la misma ruta utilizada arriba para el método POST.

Comment: Entonces ¿Puedo guardar en un archivo los mensajes?

Comment: Ah, ¿Y cómo se haría el post method?

Comment: @TatoBroh he agregado lo de POST, no entiendo la pregunta sobre guardarlo en un archivo. Quiza debas hacer una nueva pregunta explicando el caso. Salu2

Comment: Si no se pueden escribir los mensajes en un archivo, no se podrá hacer un chat...

Comment: Se puede, pero eso no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta acutal. Falta explicar de que lado quieres hacerlo, la plataforma, no basta saber como enviar los datos para hacer un chat. Si quieres hacer un chat esta pregunta solo es una pieza de eso. Hay muchos ejemplos completos en internet,

Comment: debes tener en cuenta que hace falta un servidor para hacerlo, no es solamente codigo en el cliente.

Comment: Dudo que haga falta servidores para lo que voy a hacer ahora. Atiende a mi perfil cuando haga la nueva pregunta.

Comment: Bueno, ya veremos, pero seguro que hace falta, no deberias descofiar de la gente que te ayuda y te hace el favor de explicarte, es irrespetuoso y no te hace crecer para nada.

Comment: Mi intención no era faltar el respeto, solo informar de mi duda.
Aparte, existen dos funciones que no me mencionastes "PUT" y "DELETE" ¿Qué se supone que hacen esas funciones?

Comment: Ah, y en todo caso no te fijes en la pregunta que está mal escrita, fíjate en la que se aclara bien el problema y la solución que se pretende conseguir:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42413/problema-con-el-redireccionamiento-en-javascript